# xml processing on a client server application in java using sockets

Tags: java, android, xml, multithreading

I am writing a client server application in java for XML processing.

I have successfully implemented a multi-threaded server that can handle multiple clients. The XML file has a number of transaction tags that are like commands for the server, instructing him to do something( they can have a number of values including binary data). So single client can send multiple commands. These commands are also processed in separate threads that I create using Executors. I have successfully transmitted an xml file and executed its commands.

I am stuck while I am trying to incorporate additional functionality. I want the transfer to resume from the point where it stopped say due to a network disconnection. For this I am splitting the file into bundles and then transmitting these bundles and keeping a track of the last bundle successfully transmitted (through acknowledgement) so that the transmission can resume from the bundle number last transmitted. Obviously there are other fields like total number of bundles to be transmitted and so on.

Now suppose some part of the XML file is transmitted and received at the server when the network is disconnected. This part may have some transaction tags or commands.

**I want them  to be processed by the server without waiting for the complete file to be received**. In fact the correct solution would be to read the XML file being received and keep calling the command handler as soon as a complete transaction tag is received, without waiting for the complete XML file to be received.

One naive way of doing it would be to create my XML file line by line, that is having line separators for each line and then reading the socket line by line to determine location of transaction tags. I would be really grateful if anybody can give me a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to write your XML line by line. You can use a [SAX](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_sax_parser.htm) parser.

The parser will read the input and dispach events for each tag it reads. The parser will be responsible for buffering the input and notify your code when a TAG start or end.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out and will get back.

Comment: The problem that I am facing now is this. The file is split into bundles so a bundle may not have a start document tag. It may just start from the middle of text of some element. How will SAX parse this? I actually need to read and append it to the text already read in the previous connectivity interval

Comment: Use sax only to read the document(do not use validation). But if your goal is just reassemble the file i cant imagine a reason to use a parser. If is the case use a stringbuffer or a randomacessfile to join the XML again

Comment: Yes I am trying to read without validation. Will get back. I am not just reassembling the file. I am synching the file between the client and the server and also I am firing handlers as soon as I get a transaction tag completely before waiting fro the entire xml file to be received at the server. Thanks